# resource for learning about predicates

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, predicate

are there any good tutorials online for learning about the c# 2.0 language feature "predicates"?

i'm trying to learn how to use predicates along with linq to sql to modify my queries

what i am trying to do is query a table of customers and filter it based on changing criteria. for example

- find all customers who have zipcode = 90210
- find all customers who are male
- find all customers who are male AND > have zipcode = 90210

right now i am doing this using if/else statements which feels pretty wrong

also, it's possible that i'll have to add other filters so i want a flexible solution to this problem that's easy to extend without breaking anything (open closed principle i think)

Comment: Re your comment - indeed, most LINQ operations have "deferred execution" (nothing happens until you iterate it) allowing you to "compose" a query gradually - adding filters / sorts / projections etc over a series of steps. Only things like Count(), Max() etc execute immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(btw - the lambda-based predicates used with LINQ-to-SQL are C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5, not C# 2.0)

Well, what specifically are you trying to do?

Predicates are just filters (either as a delegate or an Expression); they don't *directly* allow you to modify the TSQL etc, unless you combine them with functions that the LINQ-to-SQL provider can handle ([these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx)), or UDFs mapped onto your data-context as composable functions (`FunctionAttribute`).

At the simplest:

who are male AND > have zipcode = 90210

```
var qry1 = from cust in ctx.Customers
          where cust.Gender == 'M' && cust.Zip = '90210'
          select cust;

var qry2 = from cust in ctx.Customers
          where cust.Zip = '90210'
          select cust;
```

Or  for a non-trivial example (a dynamic search form / combining separately)

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = ctx.Customers;
// note "gender" here is "char?" for this example
if(gender != null) query = query.Where(x=>x.Gender == (char)gender);
if(zip != null) query = query.Where(x=>x.Zip == zip);
```

etc

You can also build expression-based predicates by hand, but that is more work, and requires knowledge of the [Expression API](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/10/express-yourself.html).

Comment: what i am trying to do is query a table of customers and filter it based on changing criteria. for example

find all customers who have zipcode = 90210
find all customers who are male
find all customers who are male AND > have zipcode = 90210

right now i am using if/else which feels pretty wrong

Comment: sorry, didn't realize formatting doesn't work in here. i have updated my question so it's easier to read.

Comment: thanks mark, the query wont execute until it's tripped right? so i don't have to worry about the query being executed twice in your "combining separately" example? if so, this is EXACTLY what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

A predicate is simply a method with the following signature :

```
bool Predicate<T>(T item)
```

It represents a condition that can be verified or not by objects of type T.

It is use in link to filter enumerables in the `.Where` clause.

You can also use lambdas that return a boolean value :

```
item => item.Nickname == "ThinkBeforeCoding";
```